# Best way to add an event with delay in Meteor?

Tags: events, meteor, dom-events

I'm adding search functionality to a meteor app and want to trigger a search after a keyup event, plus 500ms or so. I don't want to call my meteor method on the server after every single keyup, since if somebody enters a sentence that's going to be... a lot of calls.

How can I add a delay to the keyup event of 500ms, but have the triggered event *cancelled* if another keyup event is detected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `underscore` package's `debounce` function. You might need to add `underscore` to your project via `meteor add underscore`. But I think it's already included by default.

```
var doSearch = _.debounce(function() {
   // do your search
}, 500);
```

More info: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: But quoting documentation you should add it anyway cause Meteor will remove it from default soon

Comment: how do you know that underscore will be removed?

Answer (score 1):

> Answered After 3 years

The accepted answer is confusing with the question as the question says "**Best way to add an event with delay in Meteor?**".

Currently Meteor 1.5.2 is latest, Below is the exact expected functionality from the question.

**Default way of writing an event listener activity**

```
Template.YourTemplateName.events({
    // inputs with either id/class as "search"
    'input #search, input .search': function(event, template){
      console.log('Searching.');
    }
});
```

**Adding Event with Expected delay to action**

```
Template.YourTemplateName.events({
    // inputs with either id/class as "search"
    'input #search, input .search': _.debounce(function(event, template){
      console.log('Searching.');
    }, 1000)
});
```

> `underscore` comes by default, you may install `lodash` using command `meteor npm install lodash`. Then import lodash to your js file as `import _ from 'lodash';`